# How do I connect to kafka cluster on Virtualbox?

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtualbox, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Here's my setup on local: 3 VMs (using Virtualbox), kafka and zookeeper installed on all three. They are all talking to each other as well.

I am trying to use kafka-console-producer from my local, which requires broker-list. I am supplying the IPs of my VMs but it doesn't seem to be working. I've tried the advertised.host properties on the VMs too but has no effect for me. Here's my server.properties from the three machines:

Server 1:

```
broker.id=4
port=9092
host.name=10.30.3.4
advertised.host.name=10.30.3.4
advertised.port=9092
zookeeper.connect=10.30.3.4:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

Server 2:

```
broker.id=3
port=9092
host.name=10.30.3.3
advertised.host.name=10.30.3.3
advertised.port=9092
zookeeper.connect=10.30.3.3:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

Server 3:

```
broker.id=2
port=9092
host.name=10.30.3.2
advertised.host.name=10.30.3.2
advertised.port=9092
zookeeper.connect=10.30.3.2:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

My virtualbox also has port forwarding setup:
[image]
Similarly for other two machines too ports are only tweaked a bit.

I am able to connect to zookeeper just fine, so:

```
bin/zkCli.sh -server 127.0.0.1:9999
```

is able to connect to zookeeper on VM. But if I try connecting kafka-console-producer it fails when I try sending messages:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 127.0.0.1:9502 --topic partition2replica2 --timeout 3000
```

leads to:

```
[2016-02-17 15:06:36,943] WARN Property topic is not valid (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
hi
there
[2016-02-17 15:07:23,699] WARN Failed to send producer request with correlation id 3 to broker 3 with data for partitions [partition2replica2,1] (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SyncProducer.scala:103)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:103)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:103)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply$mcV$sp(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:101)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.kafka$producer$async$DefaultEventHandler$$send(DefaultEventHandler.scala:255)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$dispatchSerializedData$2.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:106)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$dispatchSerializedData$2.apply(DefaultEventHandler.scala:100)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.dispatchSerializedData(DefaultEventHandler.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.tryToHandle(ProducerSendThread.scala:105)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:88)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread$$anonfun$processEvents$3.apply(ProducerSendThread.scala:68)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:547)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.processEvents(ProducerSendThread.scala:67)
    at kafka.producer.async.ProducerSendThread.run(ProducerSendThread.scala:45)
[2016-02-17 15:07:25,318] WARN Failed to send producer request with correlation id 7 to broker 3 with data for partitions [partition2replica2,1] (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SyncProducer.scala:103)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:103)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:103)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply$mcV$sp(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer$$anonfun$send$1.apply(SyncProducer.scala:102)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:101)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.kafka$producer$async
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here? Any ideas? (I can provide ifconfig output if anyone wants). Any help will be appreciated.

[Edit 1]: Adding output of zookeeper quorum:

```
That seems to be in quorum:
echo stat| nc 10.30.3.2 2181
Received: 81
Sent: 80
Connections: 1
Outstanding: 0
Mode: follower
Node count: 149

echo stat| nc 10.30.3.3 2181
Received: 660
Sent: 664
Connections: 1
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x600000109
Mode: leader
Node count: 149

echo stat| nc 10.30.3.4 2181
Received: 293
Sent: 295
Connections: 1
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x600000109
Mode: follower
Node count: 149
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand your setup, the zookeepers on each node should also been in Quorum with each other to support the 3 kafka servers instances as one cluster. You have provided kafka config only, so I cannot make out if they are configured that way.

You can check by using the 4 letter command on each zookeeper node like below

```
echo stat | nc <zk ip> <zk port>
echo mntr | nc <zk ip> <zk port>
```

One should be a "leader" and other two should be "followers".

I am not sure if they will work as expected if they are not configured to be in quorum.

Comment: Just added the output of those commands in the main question too. I think the issue may have something to do with advertised port on kafka and how to access it using VM. I was successfully able to connect to zookeeper on VM from local after setting up simple port forwarding (as i mentioned in the original post).

Comment: Got it. I am not sure if the issue is due to Kafka or port forwarding configuration on VirtualBox ; as I understand the client will be provided the IP and Port under advertised.host.name and advertised.port which is actually 10.30.3.X/9092 . Now those are different when you are trying to connect from host. May be some correction would be required in port forwarding rules and appropriate changes in advertise.* options.  Can you try to use the HOSTIP/PORT in advertise.host and advertise.port and test ?

Comment: So I tried adding 10.30.3.* or 10.0.2.15 both in forwarding rules and tried both with 127.0.0.9502, it won;t work. Sorry about the 127.0.0.1:5656 in broker list, I created a tunnel from here to whatever I used in port forwarding at that time - which also didn't work :(

Comment: I've fixed the 127.0.0.1:5656 -> 127.0.0.1:9502

Comment: @KP Have you tried the option of using the HOST IP/HOST PORT from Virtualbox forwarding rules , for example 127.0.0.1/9502  as advertise.host.name and advertise.port for the first instance(broker.id=4)

Comment: advertised port I believe is the real ip of the machine and not 127.0.0.1, what's the reasoning behind suggesting that?

Comment: Please refer to this link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ which talks about something additional about advertise.host.name and advertise.port ; which could relate to the setup you have

Comment: Just tried that too, doesn't work. Used 127.0.0.1 as advertised.host.name and 9502 as advertised.port.

Comment: Will recheck my setup which I had done and check what is different

Comment: Thanks appreciate it, posting the configs will be helpful too :)

Comment: @KP Apologies for late response. Having been a little caught up. I tried to work on the setting equivalent to yours with the port forwarding setup and I get errors similar to the ones mentioned by you. I am trying to think of all hacks possible of making this work , i don't think that kafka likes NAT or port forwarding setups. It needs the consumers or producers in routable domain.